# Parallel OpenVPN Connection Over multiple Libvirt Network Interfaces

Tags: openvpn, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

Let's Say That I have 20 VMs (Host: Ubuntu, Using Qemu-KVM, libvirt) and that I would use different network interfaces for different groups of vms. (1-6 using Network1, 7-15 using Network2, 16-20 using Network3). The Network interfaces were created by libvirt.
And I would want The network interfaces to use a openVPN connection. (So Network1 uses conn1, Network2 uses conn2, Network3 uses conn3) to serve the purpose which is that the first group of vms all use the conn1 and so on... 
What I wouldn't want is to run the openvpn inside each VM.
So is there a way?
if so how advanced is the way (cause I'm kinda a newbie :) )
and How would I go about it? (I would even appreciate knowing what subject of networking I should study)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create four bridges:

   - Internet access bridge
   - Network 1
   - Network 2
   - Network 3

Notice "Network N" bridges don't need to have an IP assigned on the host.

2. Create three VPN Gateway VMs:

   - VPN1 participates in "Internet" and "Network 1"
   - ...
3. Each of these VMs should run one OpenVPN client, which accesses its VPN through the "Internet" interface. The other "Network N" interface is for communicating with other VMs who happened to live the corresponding network bridge
4. The rest VMs should only participate in the corresponding network (so no direct communication with the host) and have their corresponding VPN VM to be the default gateway.

I think this is easiest configuration to build and understand. Another way is to run all VPNs on the host and use *policy routing* or *VRFs* (which is essentially same thing) or *network namespaces* to assign VMs to corresponding VPN.

Comment: Oh thanks for your help. although I don't understand what you just said 100%, at least I now know what to look into.
P.S: sorry I can't upvote. not enough rep